# "Registered S3 methods overwritten" message from imported package

Tags: r, r-package, r-s3

Whenever I load my package, I get this message:

> ```
> Registered S3 methods overwritten by 'expss':
>   method                 from 
>   [.labelled             Hmisc
>   as.data.frame.labelled base 
>   print.labelled         Hmisc
> ```

Indeed, I use functions from both `expss` and `Hmisc` in my package. Here are the related lines in NAMESPACE:

> ```
> ...
> importFrom(Hmisc,label)
> ...
> importFrom(expss,apply_labels)
> importFrom(expss,set_var_lab)
> importFrom(expss,unlab)
> importFrom(expss,var_lab)
> ...
> ```

However, none of the S3 methods are imported.

I use RStudio and the NAMESPACE is generated by `roxygen2`. I declare no other S3 methods related to those functions.

I know I could use only one package but this is not what I'm asking (I don't understand the problem which could mean something deeper, and I want to keep a compatibility with both packages).

Moreover, I wonder if the fact that `print.labelled` is mentioned could mean that there is a print reference in my package, which would be very unexpected. (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> on `print` only pointed to examples or vignettes)

Why are these methods overwritten if I don't even import them in the first place?

Comment: Maybe you should subscribe and then post this on the R package development mailing list? (Technically those are not warnings in standard R parlance.)

Comment: @42- you think this is a problem with `Hmisc` or `expss` package? I doubt this because I had the same problem with another, `DescTools` which I then removed and replaced by something else. Also, I'm not sure what exactly do you call "development mailing list", their github maybe?

Comment: @42- I already did of course, but without further explanation, I cannot see how this relates to my problem. I only want to fix whatever is causing this message to show (as you said, this is not a warning). If you think that this is related to something in particular, or that StackOverflow is not fit for this question, please say it explicitly. For now, all I understand of your comments is "go seek for help elsewhere" and this is quite confusing to me. I'm very sorry if I misunderstood what you meant.

Comment: Well, when I did the precise search that I specified the second hit was the link to the page with information and links to allow subscription. Since I am already subscribed to that mailing list, I knew that you had not yet followed my suggestion. That mailing list is a venue where the human eyes and brains attached to it are the world's experts at such issues. I wasn't giving you a go away message, but was rather suggesting a very specific action that had a higher probability of success than waiting here. List address for the search-phobic:_subscribe_first_  <r-package-devel@r-project.org>

Comment: @42- I'm not search-phobic, but I may be pretty much mailing-list-phobic. An explicit message would then have been "Experts are not on SO but on this mailing list, you would have better answers by subscribing than by waiting here". Still, thank you very much for your suggestion. I'll definitely subscribe if no one can answer my question here.

Comment: I have the same issue. Did you figure out a solution  ?

Comment: @D_Williams no, I ended up removing those dependencies, I had too much anyway. Still, I'd gladly hear about any solution, so don't hesitate to post and answer if you manage to find one.

Comment: @Dan Chaltiel i did not and was thinking to remove as well or put in suggest